# Async task not loading data

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, contacts

Code

```
    public class ContactSettings extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView contactsList;
    private List<ContactsHelper> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;
       View rootView;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_contact, container, false);



        contactsList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.usersList);
        //Add the data first
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        //and then create a object and pass the lis
        mAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(contacts);

        contactsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        contactsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        contactsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        COntacts runner = new COntacts();


        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
    }

    private class COntacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                        if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id},
                                    null);
                            if (phoneCursor != null) {
                                if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                    String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                                    contacts.add(new ContactsHelper(name, phoneNumber));
                                    phoneCursor.close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            return "Download failed";
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

It used to work in the main thread but was slow so I thought of using `Asynctask` but im new to this and the tutorials online aren't clear so can someone please tell me whats wrong in this and how can I fetch the contacts in background without it being slow...............................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see in the code you didn't use `urls` parameter in `doInBackground`. And you need to pass `contacts` to `onPostExecute` which runs in `UI Thread` :

```
private class COntacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<ContactsHelper>> {

@Override
protected List<ContactsHelper> doInBackground(Void... urls) {
   List<ContactsHelper> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
   ...
   return contacts
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<ContactsHelper> result) {
    contacts.addAll(result);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You need to execute `runner` object in you code :

```
runner.execute()
```

Comment: taking like 5 seconds to load... the code on the UI thread was just taking around 2... how can i make it faster and i thought runnning in background was going to make it faster

Comment: You can display a `progressDialog` to the user while loading data from background. When you load data in background your app will not freeze. User is able to work with your app, but loading does not become faster.